# Create a linked server connection between Azure SQL DB and Azure Cosmos DB

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-cosmosdb

I have a Cosmos DB and SQL Db in Azure.

Can I create a linked server to Cosmos Db in SQL Db, and then write SQL queries to documents in SP present in SQL Db. Is this technically possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Azure SQL Server [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/linked-servers/create-linked-servers-sql-server-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017) said that Azure SQL database doesn't support create linked servers:
[image] 
But SQL Server does. I searched some demos and I think may be useful for you.

Here are the two samples about Azure Cosmos DB linked server:

1. [Connect to Cosmos DB Data as a Linked Server](https://www.cdata.com/kb/tech/cosmosdb-odbc-linked-server.rst/)
2. [Query Azure CosmosDB from a SQL Server Linked Server](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/mr-fox-sql/2017/09/25/query-azure-cosmosdb-from-a-sql-server-linked-server/)

Hope this can helps you.

Answer (score 1):

> Can I create a linked server to Cosmos Db in SQL Db, and then write
>   SQL queries to documents in SP present in SQL Db. Is this technically
>   possible ?

You could use [copy activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-overview) in [Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/) to achieve your requirements.

Please configure [Cosmos db as source linked service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-cosmos-db) and [SQL db as sink linked service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-sql-database).

In addition,you could configure [stored procedure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-sql-database#invoking-stored-procedure-for-sql-sink) in from SQL db sink.